# Select latest topic from a category (SQL and PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to be able to select the latest topic that was posted to a category by selecting it through an SQL query.

I have two tables that I'm going to use.

- categories
- topics

A topic row knows what category it belongs to because  `topics.topic_cat` should match with `categories.cat_id`.

I want to loop through all the categories and show the latest topic posted to them.  It looks something like this.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['cat_name'] . ' Latest Post is ' . $row['topic_name'];
}
```

This would be an example of what it would look like if it was executed.

```
category1 Latest Post is "latest post"
category2 Latest Post is "latest post"
category3 Latest Post is "latest post"
```

and so on...

What SQL query could I use to select this?

Here are my table structures.

**categories**

- cat_id
- cat_name
- cat_description

**topics**

- topic_id
- topic_name
- topic_date
- topic_cat
- topic_by

Comment: Please post your table structures.

Comment: @RobertColumbia I've posted them, is that enough information?  Ask me if you need more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Update

This is a more efficient query that gets you the same result. It will perform better because the subquery is uncorrelated (doesn't use any data) from the outer query

```
SELECT cat_name, topic_name, latest as topic_date 
FROM categories c
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT topic_name, topic_cat, MAX(topic_date) latest 
    FROM topics
    GROUP BY topic_cat
     ) as t
ON c.cat_id = t.topic_cat
```

[**Live demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0cd705/2)

You asked about `LEFT JOIN` vs `JOIN`: The first means that if any category has no topic, you still want it included in results. The topic name and date will just be `null`.  `JOIN` means that you want results to include only categories with a matching topic. So you can alter either of my queries to your liking.

## Original answer

This is what you need:

```
SELECT c.cat_name, t.topic_name, t.topic_date 
FROM categories c
LEFT JOIN topics t ON c.cat_id=t.topic_cat
WHERE topic_date = (
    SELECT MAX(t2.topic_date)
    FROM topics t2
    WHERE t2.topic_cat = t.topic_cat
)
```

This query will return only the latest topic from each category. Each result has fields:

```
cat_name | topic_name | topic_date
```

Once you've executed your query, you can run your loop as you wish:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['cat_name'] . ' Latest Post is ' . $row['topic_name'];
}
```

[**Live demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29f0ee/10)

Comment: Amazingly simple answer!  Works just as I intended.  Thanks for the live demo as well.

Comment: Is there any reason for using `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN` though?

Comment: @ZacharyVincze see my updated answer. I also included a demo of what `LEFT JOIN` looks like if a category has no matching topic